# How to start in the middle of command input

Tags: emacs, emacs23

How can I have emacs start and be in the middle of a command input? Particularly, I want emacs to start in the middle of a command input `find-file` with a message in the small buffer saying:

```
Find file: ~/
```

and the cursor at the last character of it so that I can continue typing the remaining path to open the file I want.

Comment: Currently, it starts in the working directory of the current file, or $HOME if you're not in any file doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit that my lisp is a bit rusty, but this works for me.  Drop it in your `~/.emacs` file (or whatever init file you are using):

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
          (lambda ()
            (if (= (length command-line-args) 1)
                  (call-interactively 'find-file))))
```

If you call `emacs` with no arguments, like this:

```
sawa@localhost:~$ emacs
```

It will invoke `find-file` for you.  If, on the other hand, you invoke `emacs` with an argument, such as a filename, like this:

```
sawa@localhost:~$ emacs somefile.txt
```

It will default to just visiting `somefile.txt`

Comment: `emacs --eval '(dired ".")' -f find-file` will do the same thing although I'm not sure about why to want to run both `dired` and `find-file`.

Comment: @DeokhwanKim It was my mistake to mention dired. It actually wanted find-file.

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer because I can write that in the init file rather than doing shell scripting outside of emacs.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute one of the following commands on the command prompt or make a shell script containing it appropriately:

```
$ emacs -f find-file         # if you want to start Emacs in the current direcoty
$ (cd ~; emacs -f find-file) # if you want to start Emacs in your home diretory
```

From the [emacs(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/emacs) man page:

> **`-f`** *function*, **`--funcall`** *function*
>
> > Excute the lisp function *function*

Comment: It was my mistake to mention dired. It actually wanted find-file

Comment: Thanks. I see the elegance of this answer.